# jQuery UI elements too large

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Here's the page in question: http://bit.ly/m5cyjx

There's hardly any code or styling. It seems that the jQuery UI elements (in this case - select menu & button) are much too large. By default they should be quite small, not much higher than the max height of this sentence.

I've taken the jQuery UI CSS straight from their website, and I have similarly taken the jQuery select menu CSS from that project creator's website. Even with the default code, there is no change in the problem.

Any help?

**Edit** Also, there are no arrows on the right of the select menu, as there should be by default. Take a look at the project page: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

Comment: What browser are you using?  It looks fine to me in Firefox 4.

Comment: You should add a CSS reset so the size doesn't depend on browser default (especially since the jQuery UI stylesheet uses "em")

Comment: The most of your issues can be easily solved by analyzing what Firebug (in Mozilla Firefox) or Developer Tools (in Google Chrome) are displaying. This is combination of your current styling + custom jQuery UI styling + lack of required images etc.

Comment: @Sennheiser The first link you give is now dead and the project page doesn't seem to show the effect anymore. Anyway, I had the same problem with jQuery menu and realised I was using an out-of-date CSS file. The menu widget came in with jQuery UI 1.9 so maybe you should check that you have an up-to-date version of the jQuery UI CSS files for your project. That solved the arrow position, but I still needed the fixes suggested here to solve the size problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of the following styling (style.css, line #10):

```
#main {
    margin-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

You have very big size for font in `#main`, and because jQuery UI correctly inherits other styles, the buttons are also big.

Change the above snippet into the following and it will look better (at least buttons):

```
#main {
    margin-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I tried messing with that, but it never approaches this look: http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/ I even tried taking out all stylesheets of mine, and it still doesn't look close to the example.

Comment: @Sennheiser Use Firebug (in Firefox) or Developer Tools (in Google Chrome) to check which styles are applied to buttons and investigate the issue that way. The issue with size of the buttons can be easily solved by the fix I have provided you above. If you have any additional question, please let me know.

Comment: Tadeck - My issue is that even without any custom styles, the buttons appear much differently than they do on the jQuery UI website.

Comment: @Sennheiser the jQuery ui website sets the font-size in the body to 10px, similarly as Tadeck suggested you do.  If you set the font-size to 10px in your main div, your jQuery ui elements will look exactly the same as they do on the UI website.

Comment: @Sennheiser There are differences, because: 1) you have non-standard theme (as stated in CSS file, your theme is available [under that link](http://bit.ly/j2E7Ql)), 2) you are missing at least 6 images needed to display it according to CSS (use Developer Tools or Firebug to determine them or copy the files you have to `/css/images`). Did it help?

Comment: be sure you've got /themes/base/jquery.ui.spinner.css included in your CSS stack (per my answer)

Answer (score 14):

Yeah. I don't get why this is the default in JQuery UI. I don't think *anyone* wants buttons that big.

Here's how I solve it. Add this to the <head> of the html file.

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* make default button size sane */
    .ui-button-text {
        font-size: .6em;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Definitely the easiest solution. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

I found that in there UI pages they have this css code:

body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

so they are heavily scaling their font size down. Putting this in your page could solve the issue, it worked for me.

Comment: Most of ThemeRoller themes do this to be able to do the conversion: `1em = 10px` https://forum.jquery.com/topic/adjust-button-size#14737000000744502

Answer (score 2):

The two css rules controlling the sizes are

Line 424 of jquery-ui.css

```
input.ui-button {
    padding: .4em 1em;
}
```

and Line 59 of jquery-ui.css

```
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Segoe UI, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

Adjust the padding and font-size until it looks how you want it to look.

Answer (score 0):

remove the ui-widget class.

i *think* the pattern is

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <div class="ui-widget-header">
    </div>

    <div class="ui-widget-content">
    //your button could go here 
        <div class="ui-button">click me</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to stumble across this, but try adding the DOCTYPE html to your document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

before your opening html tag.

Answer (score 0):

@Tadeck i was having a similar issue, and changing the font size did the trick :) thank you!

also, before i read this, i was trying to see if changing the font sizes of the inner content worked, but for reasons i describe below it did not. (so don't do what i did! =P)

**script that calls the jquery tabs function to make the tabs**

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

**markup the script needs to build the tabs**

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-main">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-stuff"> Other Stuff </a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-main"> 
       <!-- where i put unformatted content, like headers and description paragraphs -->
       <div> formatted inner content here (for graphs/visual content/tables/etc) </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-stuff"> 
       <!-- where i put unformatted content, like headers and description paragraphs -->
       <div> formatted inner content here (for graphs/visual content/tables/etc) </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

turns out setting the styles inline for divs inside each tab div is doesn't change the size of the tabs. i had to change the font size for the .ui-widget class in the css file that was generated from the jQuery UI theme i rolled. and changing the UI's stylesheet really isn't necessary since you can set the font sizes on the site for the jQuery theme roller before you download your custom theme. i just forgot to do that. i'll chalk that up to one of my more derpy moments.

[edit] this obviously wasn't for a UI button, but similar concept and issues apply

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem.. my spinner controls were ugly, huge, and laid out in a horizontal rather than vertically stacked...

I got to looking at my master html file (actually a razor MVC layout file) and noticed I needed to include ***/themes/base/jquery.ui.spinner.css***

Now my spinners look great!

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the other answers, but none seemed to work properly.
Some did not change anything and some had adverse side-effects (like scaling everything down).

This finally did the trick:

```css
.ui-widget
{
 font-size: 75%;
}
```